# if statement not reading variables

Tags: php, if-statement

I wrote a program that reads data from a csv (saved as Unicode format in SQL Studio) and then does a few comparisons and prints out the results.

For some reason this simple if statement returns false eventhough when the data is printed it shows the correct results:

```
    foreach ($complete as $key => $val){    
    $INVOICE = 'INVOICE';
    $InvoiceType = $complete[$key][9];
    echo 'comparing' . $InvoiceType.'to'. $INVOICE;
         if ($InvoiceType == $INVOICE){
     echo 'I am inside a invoice';
     }
     else if ($InvoiceType == 'CREDIT'){
     $PayeeDocumentType = 'CM';echo 'I am inside a credit';
  }
  }

 ---------  Results  --------- 
comparingINVOICEtoINVOICEcomparingINVOICEtoINVOICE
```

Comment: that result doesn't look correct. How can it echo "comparingINVOICEtoINVOICE" twice?

Comment: Please paste the output of `var_dump($InvoiceType);`

Comment: can you `var_dump` `$complete`?

Comment: It is a part of a loop.  Here are the results: 
comparingINVOICEtoINVOICEstring(13) "INVOICE" comparingINVOICEtoINVOICEstring(13) "INVOICE"

Comment: James' is right, the only way the result should be **comparingINVOICEtoINVOICEcomparingINVOICEtoINVOICE** is if you've excluded an enclosing for loop and the $InvoiceType does not equal CREDIT or INVOICE...

Comment: that's alarming... it should be string(7) "INVOICE"

Comment: Here's a part of the results of var_dump $complete:
array(19) { [0]=> array(10) { [0]=> string(5) "791" [1]=> string(13) "1608424" [2]=> string(15) "BENV5649" [3]=> string(57) "K&C Investigators-TEST VENDOR" [4]=> string(13) "1235.01" [5]=> string(19) "04/01/2011" [6]=> string(11) "10-111" [7]=> string(11) "EFT-JP" [8]=> string(21) "1330.010000" [9]=> string(13) "INVOICE" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First guess try

```
$InvoiceType = trim($complete[$key][9]);
```

Also note the output of the var_dump in "view source" of the page. Basically see the raw output bring sent to the browser, maybe there are some invisible characters there.

Answer (score 1):

My only guess is that `$complete[$key][9]` is an object and not a string.

What happens if you add `print_r($complete[$key][9])` somewhere or modify the 2nd line of code to:

```
$InvoiceType = (string) $complete[$key][9];
```

Comment: print_r($complete[$key][9]) prints "INVOICE". I also did gettype and it returned "string"